# how to hide some models in django grappelli admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-grappelli

How to hide some of the models?

I need them registred to be used by other models, while calling via FK or nested etc.

I found one solution which is rather much about view layer of (MVC) 
http://blog.jholster.com/post/1534211028/hide-app-names-in-django-admin

I would like to set it in admin.py, that some of registred models are hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the models are in your application, just don't register them in the first place. If the model is in a third party app like the django.contrib.auth then use `AdminSite` `unregister` method. You can put this in any `admin.py` or `urls.py` important is to be discovered by the `admin.autodiscover`.

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

admin.site.unregister(User)
```

Comment: will they be avaliable to other models? I wrote: `I need them registred to be used by other models, while calling via FK or nested etc.`

Comment: Yes. You just don't want to see them listed in admin. Give it a try. Import the model and unregister.

Comment: so first register and then unregister, or just unregister, or none of this?

Comment: Ok. If the models are in your application, just don't register them in the first place. If the model is in a third party app like the django.contrib.auth then use unregister.

Comment: update your answer with content of last comment and I would glady accept it.